# opening new window using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this registration form and when Submit button is clicked 
  `<form action="viewReg.php">` will pop up using bootstrap modal. together will the value i input on the form. i already know how to get those value from the input fields. i just wanna to pop up the result using modal `viewReg.php`

i tried http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals
but it doesn't have guide for external link using Forms.

**edit**
There are two pages.. Registration.html and viewReg.php

I'm new to coding.

```
<form action="viewRegistration.php" method="post" >

  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>USN</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="usn" placeholder="USN #"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;"></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td ><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" placeholder="Your Birthday"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Place of Birth</td>
    <td> 
        <select name="pob">
        <option value="Manila">Manila</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Course</td>
    <td><select name="course">
        <option value="Bachelor of Science in Information Technology">BS in Information Technology</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>  
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

[image]
  [image]

Comment: I think your question has nearly nothing to do with the proper use of a bootstrap modal. What you want (I'm guessing) is to get the result of viewReg.php in page without reloading so that you can add it directly to your page content (for example within a bootstrap modal dialog) via JavaScript. Therefore you need to utilize Ajax in one way or another.

Comment: i know how to get the result of viewReg.php. What i want is to open a new window (viewReg.php) when submit button is clicked. I just want it to be like bootstrap modal. Anyway, I'm thinking of using lightBox.

Comment: open a new window != bootstrap modal (or you would need to open the modal directly after opening the new window which kinda would kill the sense of it)...

Answer (score 2):

here is an example on how to use forms with bs3 modals  :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0fscmf3L/17/)**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalNorm">
    Launch Normal Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalNorm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" 
                   data-dismiss="modal">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control"
                      id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"/> Check me out
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>


            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should I place the code for the form and for the viewReg.php? What I want is pop up viewReg.php using modal.. Basically it's like opening new window. By means of bs3 modal

Comment: One more thing registration form is different page. And so with .php file

Comment: you can use an include for this kind of stuff !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

would something like this but adjusting it to your classes